# How to Load More Than One CSV Using Highcharts Data Module

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to load multiple csv files into one chart so that I can use drilldowns. I cannot use a single csv with multiple columns because each dataset has differing amounts of observations or rows. I figured out how to load more than one csv using nested $.get() functions. However, Highcharts will only plot the last data set that is referenced. I tried writing the code in three different versions, but all will plot only the last data set that is referenced. I have researched Highcharts documentation but have not found anything that meets my requirement.

I am using Highcharts' data module to load the csv because it is simple. However, I am open to other solutions that may require file parsing. Below are samples of the three different versions I tried:

```
$.get('pref.csv', function(data1) {
    $.get('create.csv', function(data2) {
        $(chartID).highcharts({
            data: {
                csv: data2, data1
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or

```
$.get('pref.csv', function(data1) {
    $.get('create.csv', function(data2) {
        $(chartID).highcharts({
            data: {
                csv: data2,
                csv: data1
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or

```
$.get('pref.csv', function(data1) {
    $.get('create.csv', function(data2) {
        $(chartID).highcharts({
            data: {
                csv: data1
            },
            data: {
                csv: data2
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE
This is the solution to loading two or more csv files to use in a line chart with dates on the xAxis.

```
data.csv
Date,Mean
2001-01-01,0
2001-02-01,2.9
2001-03-01,12.9
2001-04-01,27.2
2001-05-01,38.5
2001-06-01,43.9
2001-07-01,40.7
2001-08-01,45.8
2001-09-01,50.6

data2.csv
Date,Mean
2001-01-01,2
2001-02-01,1.6
2001-03-01,8.2
2001-04-01,13.6
2001-05-01,15.6
2001-06-01,17.1
2001-07-01,15.8
2001-08-01,17
2001-09-01,13.3

function parseCSV(csvFile) {
    // empty array for storing the chart data
    var data = [];
    // Split the lines
    var lines = csvFile.split('\n');
    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        if (lineNo != 0) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            // Insert date and player count into the series
            data.push([Date.parse(items[0]), parseFloat(items[1])]);
        }
    });
    return data
}


$.get('data.csv', function(data1) {
    $.get('data2.csv', function(data2) {
        // parse data1
        var series1 = parseCSV(data1)
            // parse data2
        var series2 = parseCSV(data2)

        $('container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            series: [{
                data: series1
            }, {
                data: series2
            }],
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: please provide example of "drilldowns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data.js module expects single file. So you need to load two or more files by ajax (by $.get like you have). Then prepare custom parsing and create structure of series array.

Manual:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. After a lot of research and trial and error, I figured out how to parse the csv.